# Падает postfix, как сделать его автовключение после падения на Centos 7

Tags: centos, postfix

Проблема в том,что падает postfix, как сделать так,чтоб при падении он поднимался автоматически? ОС Centos 7 с iredmail

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю, что такое _iredmail_ и как он связан с postfix-ом. Но если postfix в системе дефолтный, и управляется самостоятельно через `systemd`, то возможно это решится  добавлением `Restart=on-failure` и `RestartSec=5s` в секцию `[Service]`. Но это все костыли. Надо искать причину падения postfix-a и исправлять.

Comment: Я немного не опытный, где  можно найти [Service]? Этот когстыль нужен до разговора с хостинг провайдером, скорее всего виновато ограничение сокетов